# jquery timepicker dropdown not correctly displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

Time picker in my page displaying dropdown and picking time correctly.

But the problem is the background of the dropdown not showing properly.Half of the dropdwon template is in white and other half is in black like below

[image]

Not only timepicker and also datepicker displaying like this only.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='docs/jquery-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='docs/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='docs/jquery.timepicker.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='docs/jquery-ui.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='docs/jquery.timepicker.css' />
<script>

    $(function() {
    //setup date pickers
    $( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    $( "#dateTo" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    $('#timeFrom').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });
    $('#timeTo').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });
});
</script>
</head>
<body >


<label for="text">START TIME : </label> <input type="text"  id="dateFrom" /> <input type="text" id="timeFrom">
<label for="text">END TIME : </label> <input type="text" id="dateTo" > <input type="text" id="timeTo">
```

jquery version is 1.11.1..cant predict what is the problem here..

Can you pls help me to get rid of this?

Comment: can you create a demo on jsfiddle or plnkr with your actual CSS and HTML? Looks like you have other parts of CSS that interfere with widget

Comment: create a demo on fiddle ...

Comment: I have created..https://jsfiddle.net/z5px7v4t/    but there it is not working fully :-(

Comment: Fixed your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/rf0jt2u2/ The problem is not reproducing though. Are you sure you included all the code/css you have?

Comment: @dekkard it is working now..I think the problem is with some ui images.. thanks for your help